# Implement SQLite Xamarin.Forms - Unable to create SQLiteAsyncConnection

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement SQLite into my Xamarin.Forms Shared Assets project from this article.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/

All appears to be set up correctly tyo my novice eyes, however there seems to be a problem in creating the database connection. It says its Not able to implicitly convert type SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection to TechsportiseApp.Data.TechsportiseData

I can't work out why this is. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using static TechsportiseApp.Helpers.GlobalFunctions;
using TechsportiseApp.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TechsportiseApp.Data
{
    class TechsportiseData
    {

        public TechsportiseData(string dbPath)
        {
            database = new SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            database.CreateTableAsync<Scan>().Wait();
            database.CreateTableAsync<Timing>().Wait();
        }

        static TechsportiseData database;

        public static TechsportiseData Database
        {
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                {
                    database = new TechsportiseData(DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().GetLocalFilePath("TechsportiseData.db3"));
                }
                return database;
            }
        }

        public Task<List<Timing>> GetTimingsAsync()
        {
            return database.Table<Timing>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public Task<List<Timing>> GetTimingsNotUploadedAsync()
        {
            return database.QueryAsync<Timing>("SELECT * FROM [Timing] WHERE [Uploaded] = 0");
        }

        public Task<Timing> GetTimingAsync(int id)
        {
            return database.Table<Timing>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public Task<int> SaveTimingAsync(Timing timing)
        {
            if (timing.ID != 0)
            {
                return database.UpdateAsync(timing);
            }
            else
            {
                return database.InsertAsync(timing);
            }
        }

        public Task<int> DeleteTimingAsync(Timing timing)
        {
            return database.DeleteAsync(timing);
        }

        public Task<int> DeleteAllTimingsAsync()
        {
            return database.DeleteAllAsync(timing);
        }

        public Task<List<Scan>> GetScansAsync()
        {
            return database.Table<Scan>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public Task<List<Scan>> GetScansNotUploadedAsync()
        {
            return database.QueryAsync<Timing>("SELECT * FROM [Scan] WHERE [Uploaded] = 0");
        }

        public Task<Scan> GetScanAsync(int id)
        {
            return database.Table<Scan>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public Task<int> SaveScanAsync(Scan scan)
        {
            if (scan.ID != 0)
            {
                return database.UpdateAsync(scan);
            }
            else
            {
                return database.InsertAsync(scan);
            }
        }

        public Task<int> DeleteScanAsync(Scan scan)
        {
            return database.DeleteAsync(scan);
        }

        public Task<int> DeleteAllScanssAsync()
        {
            return database.DeleteAllAsync(scan);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hrm my Spidey senses you didn't follow the tutorial completely and thoroughly

Answer (score 1):

The first and most obvious thing is this doesn't make sense

```
static TechsportiseData database;
```

change it to this

```
readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the section of code

```
static TechsportiseData database;

public static TechsportiseData Database
{
    get
    {
        if (database == null)
        {
            database = new TechsportiseData(DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().GetLocalFilePath("TechsportiseData.db3"));
        }
        return database;
    }
}
```

Needed to be in App.cs which I didn't realize. Seems good now!